# Do either Dragon or Windows Speech Recognition use a dedicated graphics card or GPU when one is available?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, dragon-naturally-speaking, speech-recognition, windows-speech-recognition

[Dragon](https://www.nuance.com/dragon.html) and Windows Speech Recognition are two popular programs used for voice-to-text dictation and operation of a computer by voice.  On my well appointed but 7-year-old laptop, both of these programs can hang, depending on the utterance.  As I look for a new computer, it would be useful to know whether a dedicated GPU might provide some performance benefit for running them.  I'm guessing not, but would like to be sure.

---

*Meta:*  Presumably this question is not off-topic here, but if it somehow is, please advise where the question should be reposted.

Comment: I don't understand what that question is supposed to mean. In addition include the question in your body.

Comment: I don't believe they do. Speech recognition software broadly likely doesn't have much of a reason to. That is, as far as I am aware, most programs that can process spoken language can do so relatively quickly anyway, so there would likely be little benefit, if any, if it were even possible.

Comment: @Seth I've added an explanation of the question in the body.  Hopefully this clarifies things.

Comment: Windows might enable additional effects and depening on what else you do it might improve the overall performance. With notebooks you will usually be restricted to some hybrid model that allows you to switch between the on board and dedicated card. If all you do is run dragon and Windows it's unlikely that it's worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dragon Professional Individual doesn't use the GPU. The latest major release of Dragon Professional Individual was 6 years ago (Dragon Professional Individual 15 release in Aug. 2016) and since then Nuance has barely made any improvements to Dragon Professional Individual.